# Get custom text view in TabLayout - Android Design Library

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I'm building a screen with fixed number of tabs (3), with a text size of 12sp and dynamically changing text and indicator color based on the selected tab. Do not want sliding tabs.

For this, I'm setting a custom text view while creating these tabs, since I want to change the text size (there doesn't seem to be any method to change text size in TabLayout) and text color. Now, how do I retrieve the text view attached to these tabs?

It would have been a lot easier had Android Design Library's TabLayout exposed these methods.

1. Set Indicator Color
2. Set Indicator Height
3. Changing text size
4. Get Custom Text View

I did a workaround for 1 and 2 by using reflection (not sure if that's the best way). Solved 3 by using a custom text view. Looking for a way to solve 4.

Comment: Of course, the whole point of the Design Library is the match the [material design specs for tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) and that would include not changing text size, etc.

Comment: And you could have used `app:tabIndicatorColor` and `app:tabIndicatorHeight` for #1 and #2

Comment: I want to have first two tabs with two lines of text and third tab with one line of text. The spec says textSize should be 12sp when text spans across two lines and 14sp if it's on one line. This means there needs to be an easy way to set different text sizes, right?

Answer (score 3):

`TabLayout` contains a number of helpful XML attributes you may want to be aware of:

- `app:tabIndicatorColor` for setting the tab indicator color (defaults to `?attr/colorAccent` (this seems to do #1 for you)
- `app:tabIndicatorHeight` for setting the tab indicator height (this seems to do #2 for you)
- `app:tabTextAppearance` for a custom `TextAppearance` for tab text (this may allow you to do #3)
- `app:tabTextColor` for the tab's text color (this allows you to do #4)
- `app:tabSelectedTextColor` for the selected tab's text color

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `app:tabIndicatorColor` will not work for me since I need to change the indicator color based on some user action. Can I achieve this programmatically? Suggestion for indicator height will mostly work. Again, for `app:tabTextColor` and `app:tabSelectedTextColor`, I need to change this dynamically. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: TabLayout has these methods: setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(), setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(), do you have tried it?